# how to define an array index inside a string in php?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I want to do a query on a sql database, but I don't know how to define the array index as it is inside a string.

For example:

```
$query ="INSERT INTO Users(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, password)    VALUE($_POST[firstname], $_POST[lastname], $_POST[email], $_POST[password])";

mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

I tried putting single quotes around the index like I would do normally but my text editor(vim) is putting a redblock around it. So I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong.If I put double quotes around the index the left hand square bracket of goes red. If I don't put any quotes around them as in the example above I get undefined index.

Comment: Quotes around simple array references would have been syntactically correct, curly string expressions alternatively. But research bound parameters if you're using mysqli already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape your variables like this

```
// http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
$query ="INSERT INTO Users(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, password) VALUES ('".$_POST['firstname']."', '".$_POST['lastname']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['password']."')";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

or you can use mysqli_prepare

```
// http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
$query = "INSERT INTO Users (firstName, lastName, emailAddress, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss'; $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query ="INSERT INTO Users(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, password)    VALUE('".$_POST['firstname']."', '".$_POST['lastname']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['password']."')";
```

Comment: what are the full-stops for?

Comment: string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can make query like

```
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];


$query="insert into person_info(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, password) values('".$fname."','".$lname."','".$email."','".$pass."')";
```

I hope it helps you